# How to identify event is being called from Secondary tile

Tags: c#-4.0, mobile, mvvm, tile

When I run my Windows 8 application it creates a primary tile and a secondary tile.

If I click on the primary tile it should open a URL. Clicking on the secondary tile should not open the URL and instead just a splash screen, so I added `Window.Current.VisibilityChanged += Window_VisibilityChanged;` to capture the event. But this gets called when you click on both tiles.

How do I find out if the event is triggered from the primary or secondary tile?

Another thing I noticed is if I click on the secondary tile it first hits the `window_VisibilityChanged` and also goes through the `onLaunched` method of `App.xmal.cs`.

Is there a way to figure out if the event is being fired from secondary tile before it hits the `onLaunced` method?